# C++ and sqlite3- sqlite3_prepare_v2 is not working

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, sqlite

I'm using sqlite3 with C++ . But the problem is that when I debugged the code I realised that it does not, I mean `sqlite3_prepare_v2` does not extract the data from the database.

When I printed the value it extracted, it printed some garbage value. At the same time, I noticed the following warning:

> Warning   4   warning LNK4248: unresolved typeref token (01000028) for
>   'sqlite3_stmt'; image may not run .

I'm working on MS visual studio 2010 windows forms application.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

I think the linker complaint is ok. See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8376b2f0-cc36-48c8-9021-f30bda41f410/linker-warning-lnk4248-possible-problem

The following does **not** take into account that you're programming in MS managed C++, however, I hope it still provides some guidance.

sqlite3_prepare_v2 prepares the statement but does **not** execute anything.
You need to call **sqlite3_step** to execute (or partly execute) the SQL.

For an SQL statement that returns nothing (e.g. UPDATE, DELETE, INSERT) you call sqlite3_step once and it should return SQLITE_DONE if it worked.

For a statement that can return multiple rows you call sqlite3_step repeatedly. Each time the return code is SQLITE_ROW you have been returned a row of data that you can access with the 
sqlite3_column_* set of statements. When all data has been returned sqlite3_step returns SQLITE_DONE.

Code might look something like this

```
sqlite3* db;
int rc = sqlite3_open(databasePath.c_str(), &db);
std::string sql = "SELECT Id, Url FROM Url WHERE Page_Download_Reqd <> 0;";

sqlite3_stmt* statementPtr;
const char* tailPtr;
int rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql.c_str(), sql.size(), &statementPtr, &tailPtr);

bool finished = false;
do {
    int rc = sqlite3_step(statementPtr);
    switch (rc) {
        case SQLITE_ROW: {
            __int64 id = sqlite3_column_int(statementPtr, 0);
            std::string url = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(sqlite3_column_text(statementPtr, 1));
            // Do something with your data
        }
        break;
        case SQLITE_DONE:
            finished = true;
            break;
        default:
            assert(false);
    }
} while (!finished);
```

If you have variables in you SQL, e.g.

```
SELECT Id, Url FROM Url WHERE Count <> :count;
```

then you need to use one of the sqlite3_bind_* functions between the sqlite3_prepare_v2 and sqlite3_step functions. For example

```
__int count = 6;
std::string bindVarName = ":count";
rc = sqlite3_bind_int(
    statementPtr, 
    sqlite3_bind_parameter_index(statementPtr, bindVarName.c_str()), 
    count);
```